# Script to remove string up to first number

Tags: python, linux, bash

I need to write a script that will look through a folder and strip out the text from a string of an image.

```
image-w-inch-bob-bob-bob-bob-8820-AV1.jpg
image-w-inch-bob-bob-bob-bob-8820-AV2.jpg
image-w-inch-bob-bob-bob-bob-8820-AV3.jpg
image-w-inch-bob-bob-bob-bob-8820-AV4.jpg
image-w-inch-bob-bob-bob-bob-8820-AV5.jpg
image-w-inch-bob-bob-bob-bob-8820-AV6.jpg
```

I need this to be renamed to

```
8820-AV1.jpg
8820-AV2.jpg
8820-AV3.jpg
8820-AV4.jpg
8820-AV5.jpg
8820-AV6.jpg
```

Does anyone know of a script like this?

Comment: Your example data doesn't make clear where you want to cut. Should de target have 8.3 characters, start with the first digit, start with the second-last minus sign, removing everyting until the last `bob-`, remove leading minus signs after removing lowercase characters before the `.jpg`, or some other magic? What do you want when there is a space in the filename ?

Answer (score 2):

The most natural way would be to use regular expressions.

Here's an example of a python implementation:

```
import re
s = 'image-w-inch-bob-bob-bob-bob-8820-AV1.jpg'
capture_from_first_digit_re = re.compile('\D*(\d.*)')
print(capture_from_first_digit_re .findall(s)[0])
```

You can use this as you see fit in your context.

---

Short explanation:

- \D - anything *except* a digit
- \D* - keep going as long as you don't hit a digit
- \d - any digit
- .* - anything at all
- (###) - capture the matching ###

Putting it together: capture everything after the *first* digit you find.

Answer (score 0):

You most likely can do this with [rename](https://ss64.com/bash/rename.html) if your distro provides this command. For example:

```
$ rename 'image-w-inch-bob-bob-bob-bob-' '' image-w-"
```

or with PCRE Regex as the expression:

```
$ rename 's/image-w-inch-bob-bob-bob-bob-//' image-w-*
```

rename can batch rename a set of files according to a pattern match, including by regular expression. Note that the are several versions of rename which accepts different syntax, you should consult your local man and/or the command's help page to determine which version you are using and the precise syntax to use.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just trying to strip out all text before the first digit is found in the filename, something along these lines with a relatively simple regex should work in python:

```
import os
import re
# replace with the path to your file:
path = 'test/'
for filename in os.listdir(path):
    os.rename(os.path.join(path, filename),
              os.path.join(path, re.search('\d.*',filename).group()))
```

We can create a test file just for fun to see that it works:

```
import os
import re

# list out all the filenames to put into our test directory
l=['image-w-inch-bob-bob-bob-bob-8820-AV1.jpg',
   'image-w-inch-bob-bob-bob-bob-8820-AV2.jpg',
   'image-w-inch-bob-bob-bob-bob-8820-AV3.jpg',
   'image-w-inch-bob-bob-bob-bob-8820-AV4.jpg',
   'image-w-inch-bob-bob-bob-bob-8820-AV5.jpg',
   'image-w-inch-bob-bob-bob-bob-8820-AV6.jpg']

# Create Directory
os.mkdir('test')

# add in all the files
for f in l:
    open(f'test/{f}','a').close()

# All the files are there
>>> os.listdir('test')
['image-w-inch-bob-bob-bob-bob-8820-AV5.jpg', 'image-w-inch-bob-bob-bob-bob-8820-AV4.jpg', 'image-w-inch-bob-bob-bob-bob-8820-AV6.jpg', 'image-w-inch-bob-bob-bob-bob-8820-AV3.jpg', 'image-w-inch-bob-bob-bob-bob-8820-AV2.jpg', 'image-w-inch-bob-bob-bob-bob-8820-AV1.jpg']

# rename with the loop provided above:

path = 'test/'
for filename in os.listdir(path):
    os.rename(os.path.join(path, filename),
              os.path.join(path, re.search('\d.*',filename).group()))

# all the filenames have changed
>>> os.listdir('test')
['8820-AV1.jpg', '8820-AV3.jpg', '8820-AV2.jpg', '8820-AV6.jpg', '8820-AV5.jpg', '8820-AV4.jpg']
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Perl one liner solution:

```
$ ls -l
total 0
-rwxrw-r--+ 1 xxxx xxxx 0 Nov 22 08:23 image-w-inch-bob-bob-bob-bob-8820-AV1.jpg
-rwxrw-r--+ 1 xxxx xxxx 0 Nov 22 08:23 image-w-inch-bob-bob-bob-bob-8820-AV2.jpg
-rwxrw-r--+ 1 xxxx xxxx 0 Nov 22 08:23 image-w-inch-bob-bob-bob-bob-8820-AV3.jpg
-rwxrw-r--+ 1 xxxx xxxx 0 Nov 22 08:23 image-w-inch-bob-bob-bob-bob-8820-AV4.jpg
-rwxrw-r--+ 1 xxxx xxxx 0 Nov 22 08:23 image-w-inch-bob-bob-bob-bob-8820-AV5.jpg
-rwxrw-r--+ 1 xxxx xxxx 0 Nov 22 08:23 image-w-inch-bob-bob-bob-bob-8820-AV6.jpg

$ perl -ne ' BEGIN { foreach $f (glob("image-w*.jpg")) { $newf=$f, $newf=~s/(.[^\d]*)-(\d+)(.*)/\2\3/g; rename $f, "$newf" } exit } '

$ ls -l
total 0
-rwxrw-r--+ 1 xxxx xxxx 0 Nov 22 08:23 8820-AV1.jpg
-rwxrw-r--+ 1 xxxx xxxx 0 Nov 22 08:23 8820-AV2.jpg
-rwxrw-r--+ 1 xxxx xxxx 0 Nov 22 08:23 8820-AV3.jpg
-rwxrw-r--+ 1 xxxx xxxx 0 Nov 22 08:23 8820-AV4.jpg
-rwxrw-r--+ 1 xxxx xxxx 0 Nov 22 08:23 8820-AV5.jpg
-rwxrw-r--+ 1 xxxx xxxx 0 Nov 22 08:23 8820-AV6.jpg

$
```

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way to do this would be to locate the python script inside the folder the files are located. Assuming that all the filenames have the same amount of characters before the first number, then you'd need something like:

```
import os
for file in os.listdir('.'):
    if '.py' not in file: #not the python script
        os.rename(file, file[indexOfFirstNum:])
```

I haven't tested the script so try it first and modify accordingly before running it in the real folder.

EDIT: Refer to [shlomif](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5024514/shlomif)'s answer if you want the script to be more general. Regular expressions are useful for finding and matching patterns in strings.